# SQL check if date from Table 1 is between range of Table 2

Tags: postgresql, date, range

I have two tables :
Table T1 reference the id of Table T2.

```
T1
|id_t2|start_date|
|00001|2002-01-01|
|00001|2003-01-01|
|00001|2004-01-01|
|00001|2010-01-01|
|00002|2002-01-01|
|00002|2003-01-01|
|00002|2004-01-01|

T2
|id_t2|start_date| end_date |
|00001|2002-08-01|2002-12-31|
|00001|2003-01-01|2006-01-01|
|00002|2002-02-01|2002-12-31|
|00002|2003-01-01|2006-01-01|

Expected résult:
|00001|2002-01-01| <= There is no line on T2 where ids are the same and date from T1 is between T2 start_dab and end_date.
|00001|2010-01-01| <= There is no line on T2 where ids are the same and date from T1 is between T2 start_dab and end_date.
```

Comment: What have you actually tried yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   t2
                   WHERE  t2.id_t2 = t1.id_t2 AND
                          t1.start_date BETWEEN t2.start_date and t2.end_date)
```